# How to get Facebook to use "http://" instead of "https://"

Tags: facebook

How can I get Facebook to use, at least for my account, `http://` instead of the so called secure `https://` ?

Comment: By default mine uses http:, are you using some different browser settings?

Comment: What are you implying by 'so called'? If you've managed to find a vulnerability in a correctly configured https connection I'm sure there are an awful lot of people who would like to know about it :)

Comment: Out of interest, why? This seems a very unusual thing to want to do...

Answer (score 5):

`Account` > `Account Settings` > `Account Security` > Uncheck `Secure browsing (https)`

Comment: My Facebook doesn't have this option. Don't suppose you know where the option is now?

Answer (score 1):

Now facebook by default uses HTTPS. There is no option to turn it off.
Check out this link for more information:
https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/secure-browsing-by-default/10151590414803920